# Rails 6 w/ Webpacker workflow slows down HTML/CSS/JS development too much. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I used to be a huge fan of developing in Rails (Rails 4 days), but these days it's feeling like a drag. But since everyone is adopting Webpacker as standard in Rails, I finally decided to stop being stubborn and follow suit. The tutorials I've found suggest structuring your javascript folder with a styles directory where you put your SCSS instead of using the Asset Pipeline. Ever since then, it feels like every change I make to CSS or JS requires web packer to do its thing and then I can refresh (or use auto refresh) to see my tiny CSS change. I used to be able to change css and within a fraction of a second see changes in my browser. Now for every SCSS change, I have to wait 4-7 seconds before my browser sees the change (measured on a super fresh project with nothing but GSAP installed). My style for working on HTML css has always been write a few lines of CSS, save, cmd+tab, cmd+r, review change, quickly switch back to text editor. So I save and refresh A LOT.

This is adding countless hours to my development workflow. What am I doing wrong here? I can't imagine Rails devs are putting up with this so I must be doing something wrong.

With webpack-dev-server, it does significantly speed it up but its still 2-3 second wait time. I don't remember Asset Pipeline being that slow.

Comment: https://world.hey.com/dhh/rails-7-will-have-three-great-answers-to-javascript-in-2021-8d68191b

Comment: Webpacker is actually out in Rails 7. It was the best solution for the time and solved issues like using Yarn to install client side packages and good transpiler support, while sprockets was very slow and at the end of its development potential. However the browserscape has changed enough with things like import maps and ES6 support that a transpiler is a lot less neccissary. Rails 7 basically has a minimal assets handler that you can plug different backends into.

Comment: If you're using SASS make sure you're using the [Dart Sass compiler](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) which is the only currently developed compiler. If you're using the old Ruby compiler from the `sass-rails` gem that can easily explain why its taking so long.